# Is it possible for an Australian citizen to get a visa for Vietnam while in Taiwan?

Tags: visas, australian-citizens, vietnam, taiwan, embassies

I'm flying to Taiwan in January and will travel for one year or more. I'm looking at which countries are the cheapest to fly to when I'm ready to move on from Taiwan.

I see Vietnam is the cheapest and would love to go back, but as I'm an Australian citizen I'm certain I still need a visa for Vietnam.

As only a few countries recognize Taiwan I assume there would not be a Vietnamese embassy or consulate in Taiwan though Googling seems to suggest there is one. But the same Google results say that Taiwanese and people with residency can apply for Vietnam visas there.

Can I as an Aussie also apply there? If not would there be another way to get a Vietnam visa in Taiwan?

(I'm aware I could get the visa in Australia before I leave but I'm not making any plans in advance as I could decide otherwise once I'm in Taiwan. This question is to research my options.)

Comment: Have you seen http://vietnameseembassy.org/taiwan+taipei.html ? It lists the Vietnam "embassy" address, website and email in Taipei. There is also online visa application, but they send the paper visa out; you can ask the "embassy" whether they can issue you the online visa in Taipei.

Comment: Hmm, just like the other info I found via Google it only mentions visas for citizens of Taiwan. Which leaves open whether citizens of elsewhere can also use the visa service or not.

Comment: They have email address, so I suggest emailing them. As I have said above, Vietnam now has a new visa application procedure where they send you the visa on a separate sheet via postal mail, you don't need to visit the embassy or submit the passport. There may be possibility for you to apply online on Australian embassy of Vietnam, and receive it in Taipei, but you have to inquiry for that as it is unlikely such exotic scenarios would be mentioned on their website.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For visits of under 30 days, you can now apply online.

Vietnam provides e-visas to citizens of [80 countries](https://evisa.xuatnhapcanh.gov.vn/documents/20181/117155/Vietnam-Evisa-nation-list.pdf/21e0f88f-d8a0-48b8-bfdb-a0f82b0853e2), Australia being one of them, if you travel by air. You simply [apply online](https://evisa.xuatnhapcanh.gov.vn/web/guest/trang-chu-ttdt) and pay a fee of 25 USD. It takes around 3 working days to be processed, and you can then download and print it to enter/exit the country.

Comment: Well I didn't end up going from Taiwan but I almost went from Korea. It turned out there's a second fee, also of $25 USD when you arrive, making the full cost $50 USD, which was actually the price I paid the get a regular visa in my passport last time.

Comment: That's interesting, I haven't seen anything about that and was planning to go myself next year! Do you know if this extra 25 still applies? (and if so I will update my answer too)

Comment: Looks like it's confusing and I now think I got it wrong. Did some searching and apparently [the $25 stamping fee is for people with Visa On Arrival, and not for e-Visas.](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293924-i8595-k11970712-Do_I_need_to_bring_an_extra_25_for_stamping_fee_at_airport-Hanoi.html) The companies that do the VOAs seem to make it confusing on purpose and you always end up on their sites when searching for Vietnam visa info & procedures.